# Where is the detach option in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: eclipse

There used to be a contextual detach option for views in Eclipse. Here is a screenshot of it from Eclipse Juno for example.

[image: detach]

*Screenshot taken from Eclipse Juno docs.*

I am using Eclipse Kepler for Java and I don't see all of these options when I right click on a view's name, such as "Outline". All I see is the option to close it, none of the other options are available to me. The same context menu is displayed in the docs for both [Eclipse Juno](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-23.htm?cp=0_4_4_1_0) as well as [Eclipse Kepler](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-23.htm?cp=0_4_4_1_0).

Where have they moved this option? Did they in fact remove it? What options do I have for detaching views?

Comment: Do you mean detach a view from the window? You can just drag&drop it...

Comment: @Andy Yes, clicking and moving it out of the main program window works. But is this the only way to do it now? Is there no menu option for this? Like context menu or something?... maybe I'm clicking in the wrong place.

Comment: There is no menu option for this anymore, use drag as described [here](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-3e.htm)

Comment: @greg-449 OK. In my opinion, they could have kept the context menu, at least some of the options on it. Now that they have removed all of them, they might as well remove the Close option, because there is a close button (an "x") right on the tab itself that does the same thing.

Comment: Also, they need to update the docs for Kepler and remove the old screenshot as it's no longer relevant. It's just confusing when the instructions say one thing and they show something else on the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grab specific tab and drop it outside eclipse, for example onto a titlebar, so it won't attach itself to different view but will become detached. I hope it helps :)

Comment: OK. So the answer is that there is no such option, not anymore. Clicking and dragging the view out of the main Eclipse program window is the only way to do it now.